# Accessing double pointer structures in a function

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was trying to use a double pointer structure as array of structures.
It was working fine when i write the entire code in main().
Below is the working code:

```
xkumapu@lxapp-2 cat struct2.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef struct conn_s{
    int no;
    char name[32];
}conn_t;
int main(){
    int i=0, n;
    conn_t **connections;
    printf("How many students?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

    connections[i] = (conn_t*)malloc(sizeof(conn_t));
            printf("Enter no,name of student\n");

            scanf("%d%s", &connections[i]->no, &connections[i]->name);
    }

    printf("The student details you entered are");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("%d      %s", connections[i]->no, connections[i]->name);
            free(connections[i]);
    }

    return 1;
}

xkumapu@lxapp-2
xkumapu@lxapp-2 ./struct2
How many students?
3
Enter no,name of student
1 pavan
Enter no,name of student
2 suresh
Enter no,name of student
3 ramesh
The student details you entered are1      pavan2      suresh3      ramesh
```

But, when i use the same code in a function it is not working.

```
xkumapu@lxapp-2 cp struct2.c  struct1.c
xkumapu@lxapp-2 vi struct1.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef struct conn_s{
    int no;
    char name[32];
}conn_t;
int data(){
    int i=0, n;
    conn_t **connections;
    printf("How many students?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

    connections[i] = (conn_t*)malloc(sizeof(conn_t));
            printf("Enter no,name of student\n");

            scanf("%d%s", &connections[i]->no, &connections[i]->name);
    }

    printf("The student details you entered are");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("%d      %s", connections[i]->no, connections[i]->name);
            free(connections[i]);
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(){
    data();
return 1;
}
Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.
:wq
"struct1.c" 41L, 874C written
xkumapu@lxapp-2 gcc -o struct123 struct1.c
xkumapu@lxapp-2 ./struct123
How many students?
3
Segmentation fault
xkumapu@lxapp-2
```

Can you please help me in understanding the problem.

Comment: Someone likes vim :)

Comment: *Always* use `gcc -Wall -Werror`. Your life will be much, much better.

Comment: I'd also suggest `-Wextra`, as well as `-std=gnu99 -pedantic`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
connections[i] = ...
```

This line reads from the variable `connections`, which is uninitialized. This causes undefined behavior in both programs. (That means anything can happen, including appearing to "work fine".)

You can fix this by doing

```
connections = malloc(n * sizeof *connections);
```

before the loop.

---

By the way:

- `<malloc.h>` is not a standard header
- You shouldn't cast `malloc`
- You should check for errors (`scanf` can fail, `malloc` can fail, etc.)
- `1` is not a portable exit status / `main` return value (`1` indicates an error on unix and windows, but the only portable codes are `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` for success and `EXIT_FAILURE` for error).
- Passing `&connections[i]->name` to `scanf` `%s` is wrong: `%s` takes a `char *` but `&connections[i]->name` is a `char (*)[32]` (to fix this, remove the `&`)

Comment: In the real time coding, i dont know how many entries i need to store.